# my program dont recognize beetwen modules & core i am on python2

Tags: python, django, import, module

I have a python program in which I get the following error:

> ImportError: No module named core

the import causing the error is:

```
from core import wcolors
```

the file `wcolors.py` is inside a dir named `core`, there is another dir called modules, so when i run my program it give this error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "anubis.py", line 7, in <module>
from core import wcolors
ImportError: No module named core
```

**dir structure**

the dir structure follows like that

```
anubis
--anubis.py    (the script that i run)
--core
  --wcolors.py (the file i import from core)

-- modules
   [the modules i suposed to load during the execution.]
```

as another detail all files in core are compiled with .pyc extention.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a blank `__init__.py` to your `anubis` and `anubis/core` directories, and this should work.  If you don’t have the `__init__.py` file, python will not think that the directory is a module.

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file

[Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from anubis.core import wcolors
```

OR you can change a name for "core", it could be a keyword for django and python.